# How can I generate multiple reports in a single file using Crystal Reports, C#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, datatable, report

Until now I am using a `DataSet` and a single `DataTable`, to gather data from my database add rows to the table and display it to the report. Something like that:

```
report.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[1]); //ds(DataSet)
```

Is there any possible way of adding multiple `DataTables` to the `DataSet` and display each table into a new page to the report in a single document?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Even I want a solution to this problem. I cud generate a single doc. But I cant generate multiple docs of same type.